# How to retrieve the managed Router instance in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, vert.x

I was following [this](https://quarkus.io/blog/magic-control/#using-the-managed-http-server) guide to try and work with Vertx and the Router directly but i can't manage to retrieve the managed instance of Router.

I'm simply doing this:

```java
@QuarkusMainpublic 
class Main {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Quarkus.run(MyApp.class, args);
  }

  static class MyApp implements QuarkusApplication {

    @Override    
    public int run(String... args) {
      Router router = CDI.current().select(Router.class).get();
      Quarkus.waitForExit();
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

And the application fails on `CDI.current().select(Router.class).get();`
with:
`jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: No bean found for required type [interface io.vertx.ext.web.Router] and qualifiers [[]]`

My dependencies are as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"))
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc")
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured")
}
```

Is the context not fully initialized by this time?
Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the comment I tried adding the exact dependencies from the guide:

```
dependencies {
  implementation(enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"))
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc")
  implementation("io.vertx:vertx-web")
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-http")
  testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
  testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured")
}
```

But still no luck. `quarkus-vertx-http` was on the classpath before as well as a transitive dependency and that's why I didn't add it specifically.
But yeah so that did not solve it unfortunately.

Comment: The guide states that you need to add the `quarkus-vertx-http` module, which is seemingly missing in your dependencies declaration.

Comment: The `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` module might interfere with the routes configured via the Router. So, you should remove that dependency, otherwise you might get unexpected 404 responses.

Comment: @OliverMarienfeld I did try that before and just now I tried it again but still the same problem. Updated my main post about that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide you are referring to [was written for Quarkus 1.11](https://github.com/cescoffier/quarkus-magic-control/blob/f8867a7b7f366d4b8fec7f3706b5242bea843843/pom.xml#L14). Probably, you are using a more recent version which removes "unused" beans more aggressively, [see here](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#remove_unused_beans).

You have two options how to get the `Router`:

1. Obtain it via `@Inject` (this is standard for Quarkus)

```java
class MyApp implements QuarkusApplication {

  @Inject
  Router router;

  @Override    
  public int run(String... args) {
    router.get("/bye").handler(ctx -> {
      ctx.end("Goodbye.");
      Quarkus.asyncExit();
    });
    router.get().handler(ctx -> ctx.end("Hello from Quarkus!"));
    Quarkus.waitForExit();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

2. Instruct Quarkus ARC not to remove the `Router` bean by setting this in your `application.properties`:

```java
quarkus.arc.unremovable-types=io.vertx.ext.web.Router
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing the behavior you describe is that you are trying to obtain the `Router` bean programmatically, i.e. using

`CDI.current().select(...)`

When this is done, Quarkus does **not** know at build time that `Router` is needed and therefore considers it an unused bean.

The solution is to either use

`quarkus.arc.unremovable-types=io.vertx.ext.web.Router`

as @oliver-marienfeld mentions, or to restructure your code to inject the `Router` using field or constructor injection.